# JQuery Theme Roller where to put folders

Tags: jquery, html, themes, directory

I have done query themes successfully before but it's been a while. I believe I am stuck on where to put the index file and the html file so they connect. 
I have for my theme code: and its theme "A" (for html)

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/MyTheme.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/[version]/jquery.mobile-[version].min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-[version].min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/[version]/jquery.mobile[version].min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: part of your question seems to be missing

Comment: My question is : How do I structure the folders so the index file and my html file work in cohesion? -thanks